# Input from the execution line in the terminal in c

Tags: c, terminal, line

The problem that i have is that i have to write a hanois tower game in c and the input for the number of the rings must not be in the programm but the code must read the number of rings in the execution.

**Example:** ./*hanoistower 3*

And the code should get the 3 as the input. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command line arguments are propagated as strings through the main() function of your C program.

In `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` argc is the number of arguments, and argv is an array of strings containing the arguments. Note that the program name itself is always the first "argument".

As the arguments are passed as strings, you likely need to convert your `3` to an integer, which can be done with the `atoi` function. Here's a start:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int rings;
   if(argc != 2) {
       printf("Usage: %s number-of-rings\n",argv[0]);
       return 1;
   }

   rings = atoi(argv[1]);
   printf("Using number-of-rings = %d\n", rings);
...

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### I strongly suggest reading a good C programming book (in 2020, [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)).

It will be much faster than asking questions here. Don't forget to also read the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)), and debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). If you code on and for Linux, read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), and the documentation of [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (or of [musl-libc](http://musl.libc.org/), if you use it).

Hovever, the program arguments is given as a null terminated array of strings to the main function, which is usually declared as

```
 int main (int argc, char**argv) { /*...*/ }
```

if  you run your program  with `./hanoistower 3` and if your `hanoistower.c` is your source code (which you need to compile with debugging and warning enabled, i.e. `gcc -Wall -g hanoistower.c -o hanoistower` on Linux) then you have one extra argument, so

1. `argc == 2`
2. `argv[0]` is the `"./hanoistower"` string
3. `argv[1]` is the `"2"` string (use `atoi` to convert it to an `int`)
4. `argv[2]` is `NULL`

Please, please learn to use the debugger (`gdb` on Linux).

Comment: I'm very surprised that you find simpler to ask on a forum than to go to a library and take time (*several hours*) to read a good C programming book.

Comment: You have no library at your university? You know, paper textbooks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add, `argc` and `argv` to the list of `main` method parameters, as shown below:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
```

Then use `argv` as the variable to specify number of rings inside your code.