# fopen() function with a dynamic location in C

Tags: c, file, fopen

I just want to learn that how can I open a file with fopen() function from a dynamic location. I mean, for example it will be a system file and in another computer, this file can be in another location. So if I will set my location in my code not dynamically, my program will not work in another computer. So how Can I set the location dynamically for my program will find this file wherever it is?

Comment: It is not a *location* but a *file path*. See my answer for links.

Answer (score 4):

You can (and often should) pass program arguments to your `main`, thru the conventional `int argc, char**argv` [formal arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8324180/841108) of your `main`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32551887/841108).

<sup>(I am focusing on Linux, but you could adapt my answer to other OSes and platforms)</sup>

So you would use some *convention* to pass that file [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) (not a location, that word usually refers to [memory addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address)) to your program (often thru the command line starting your program). See also [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065).

You could use (at least on Linux) [getopt_long(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt_long.3.html) to parse program arguments. But there are [other ways](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html), and you can process the arguments of `main` explicitly.

You could also use some [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) to pass that information. You'll query it with [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html). Read also [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html).

Many programs have *[configuration file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file)s* (whose path is wired into the program but often can be given by program arguments or by environment variables) and are [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) them to find relevant file paths.

And you could even consider some other [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to pass a file path to your program. After all, a file path is just some string (with restrictions and interpretations explained in [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)). There are many ways to pass some data to a program.

Read also about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), notably [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). On Unix, [the shell is *expanding* the program arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398464/50557). You may want to use functions like [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) or [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) on something obtained elsewhere (e.g. in some configuration file) to get similar expansion.

BTW, be sure, when using `fopen`, to check against its failure. You'll probably use `perror` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193383/841108).

Look also into the source code of several [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (perhaps on [github](http://github.com/)) for inspiration.

Comment: Alternate ways are compile time defines and a configuration file. The different options are often mixed in professional grade software.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the environment variables, In a PC set your file location as environment variable. then read the environment variable value in your program, then open the file. This idea works both in linux and windows however you have adopt the code based on the OS to read the environment variables.

Comment: Why would you prefer environment variables to program arguments?

Comment: And why should the source code of a program using the standard [getenv](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv) needs to be adapted to various OSes? That `getenv` is available on Linux, on Windows, on MacOSX, on Android, etc.

Comment: Because if it is program arguments every time you run the program you have specify the arguments. Using environment variables makes implementation neat. that is how many of the programs access the files in standard linux implementations.

Comment: I don't understand the "implementation neat" argumentation. All OSes accept program arguments to `main` (and that is nearly required by the C standard itself). BTW, a PC running Linux is still a PC.

Answer (score 0):

Besides specifying file location at runtime through command line arguments, environment variables or configuration files, you can implement a PATH-like logic:

- Possible locations for your file are set in an environment variable:

  ```
  export MY_FILE_PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:$HOME/bin
  ```
- Your program reads that environment variable, parses its contents and checks existence of file in each specified path, with `fopen()` return status.